# How do I pass my subscription key without putting it through terminal?

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

So on the [python sdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Python) for speaker recognition using Microsoft cognitive on the CreateProfile.py I set my subscription key under the variable `subscritionKey` (note: the value set to the variable on this example isn't my actual product key) But when I place it into the one of the parameters for the function `create_profile` I get the error...

```
Exception: Error creating profile: {"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}
```

Is there I can pass my subscritionKey without having to input it constantly through terminal each time?

```
import IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper
import sys

subscritionKey = "j23h4i32h4iu3324iu234h233b43"

def create_profile(subscription_key, locale):
    """Creates a profile on the server.
    Arguments:
    subscription_key -- the subscription key string
    locale -- the locale string
    """
    helper = IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper.IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper(
        subscription_key)

    creation_response = helper.create_profile(locale)

    print('Profile ID = {0}'.format(creation_response.get_profile_id()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: python CreateProfile.py <subscription_key>')
        print('\t<subscription_key> is the subscription key for the service')
        #sys.exit('Error: Incorrect Usage.')

    create_profile(subscritionKey, 'en-us')
```

My guess is that I'm getting issues because I'm passing it as a string :/

Comment: Please notice that you have a typo (`subscritionKey`) at some points of your code and the correct spelling at others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is basically how to consume the SDK, right?

The following code works for me: In a file called `main.py` that is one level out of the folder `Identification`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./Identification')
from CreateProfile import create_profile

subscriptionKey = "<YOUR-KEY>"

create_profile(subscriptionKey, "en-us")
```

Running `python main.py` (with Python 3), that code returns

```
Profile ID = cf04bf79-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx
```

Comment: Are you sure that the API key you are using corresponds to speaker recognition? In the Azure portal it should say "API type: Speaker Recognition API (preview)"

Comment: I got it while seeing your answer. It made me dig deeper and I found out that my problem was that I the `_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY_HEADER` to my subscription key and that's what was giving me errors.

I'll mark this as the solution because it answers the question but yeah problem solved >.<